# Select values from either tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select, view

I use mySQL and I'm trying to find the rows that are in one table or in another.
Here are the tables and their fields:

```
user: id(PK), email, password, is_teacher

teacher: id, no_teacher(PK), name, id_group, no_class
teacher_information:no_teacher, cell_phone, SSN, email 

student: id, no_student(PK), name, id_group, no_class
student_information:cell_phone, email, grade, no_student

user_role: id, id_role(PK)

group_leader: id_group, id_role
group_member: id_group, id_role

group: id_group(PK), name
```

Each user (teacher or student) can be leader or member (not both) in a group, and any user can be in different groups.
What I want to is to list every people who is involved in the specific group with his name and email. 
Can Any one help me to get the sql query for this scenario?

Comment: Do you mean that you want every member of any group that has a record in the group table or are you trying to filter on a specific group?

Comment: Try to avoid using reserved words as table/column identifiers

Comment: I can't figure out what you want.  Please add sample data and desired output.

Comment: I have wrote getGroup() to return a specific group id. I only need every member of a specific group

Comment: There isn't a foreign key that is relating teacher and teacher_information and there also isn't a foreign key that relates student and student_information.

Comment: Is the `id` field that is in the user, teacher, and student class representing the primary key of the user table and then foreign keys in the teacher and student class? Currently it looks like the `id` field is the primary key for each table, which is a fairly typical standard to go by.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a field `teacher_id` to the teacher_information table and `student_id` to the student_information field

```
SELECT
    *
FROM    
    (SELECT 
        t.name as `name`,
        ti.email as `email`,
        g.name as `group_name`,
        g.id_group as `id_group`
    FROM 
        teacher t, 
        teacher_information ti, 
        group g
    WHERE
        t.id = ti.teacher_id and
        g.id_group = t.id_group
    UNION
    SELECT
        s.name as `name`,
        si.email as `email`,
        g.name as `group_name`,
        g.id_group as `id_group`
    FROM 
        student s, 
        student_information si, 
        group g
    WHERE
        s.id = si.student_id and
        g.id_group = s.id_group
    ) as a
where
    a.id_group = ?
;
```